# Linked List data-copy rotation

Tags: c, rotation, singly-linked-list

I am trying to produce a function that can rotate a linked list of single chars right one space, without relinking any individual nodes, i.e. using a data copy strategy.

I have tried multiple ways and still can not seem to produce the desired output when I print my list.

An example of the output should be:

```
happy (before rotation)
yhapp (after rotation)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct _node {
      char data;
      strut _node *next;
} NodeT


void rightRotation(NodeT *head){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL){

    }else{
        NodeT *temp1=head;
        NodeT *cur = head;
        NodeT *prev = head;
        char t1;
        while(cur->next != NULL){
            cur=cur->next;
            t1 = cur->data;
            cur->data=prev->data;
            prev=prev->next;
            cur->data=t1;
        } 
        temp1->data = cur->data;
    }
```

Comment: Show more code. For example we dont know what `NodeT` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

else block change to like this:

```
NodeT *cur = head;
char t1 = cur->data;
while(cur->next != NULL){
    char t2 = cur->next->data;
    cur->next->data = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    cur = cur->next;
} 
head->data = t1;
```

Comment: This has still the disadvantage that you are copying the data instead of changing the order of the elements of the list.

Comment: @gmug The order of the list has not changed. OP want "without relinking any individual nodes"

Comment: Although it might say that such a strategy is disadvantage if the `data` is very large or a composite type.

I think it not be said  disadvantage in this case(`char data`).

Answer (score 0):

In general you have just to set the `next` pointer of the last element to the address of the first element and the `next` pointer of the second last element to NULL and of course the pointer to the first element of the list to `head->next`.

Either you'll need more information for your function or you still need to traverse the singly linked list:
For example in the first case you would need in addition to the address of the head element, the address of the second last element and the address of the last element.

```
void rightRotation(NodeT *head, NodeT *tail, NodeT *secondLast){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL){

    }else{
        tail->next = head;
        secondLast->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

In the second case you have to traverse the singly linked list to get those adresses.

```
void rightRotation(NodeT *head){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL){

    }else{
        NodeT *secondLast = NULL;
        NodeT *tail = NULL;
        NodeT *current = head;

        tail->next = head;
        secondLast->next = NULL;

        while(current->next != NULL){
            secondLast = current;
            tail = current->next;
            current = current->next;
        }
        tail->next = head;
        secondLast->next = NULL;
    }
}
```